# JSON.parse(data) causes error

Tags: javascript, json

The problem seems to be simple:
The callback function of an AJAX post request receives this json string in parameter 'data':

```
{"result":"Torte"}.
```

When I parse it manually like this

```
var antwort = JSON.parse('{"result":"Torte"}');
```

it is ok.
But

```
var antwort = JSON.parse("'" + data + "'");
```

causes the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

With

```
var antwort = JSON.parse(data);
```

a similar error shows up (in the developer tools of Chrome):

```
VM1285:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 21
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

So it seems that 'data' contains additional characters. 
On the other hand, making the received json-string visible with

```
$("#idTest").html(data)
```

just shows

```
{"result":"Torte"}
```

No additional characters.

I have been working on this problem for several hours - without success.
Can anybody help, please.

Comment: `{"result":"Torte"}.` in your question (beggining) - the period there is a typo in the question, or maybe the error you are getting when trying to parse it?

Comment: Try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))....Moreover, JSON format doesnt allow you to start with '

Comment: If you use `$.html` it could very well be updating the DOM and not showing a html string wrapping the JSON response.

Comment: JSON.parse("'" + data + "'");   why you putting extra quote?  just do JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 3):

The data in the `JSON.parse` must be a string with a valid JSON. It is not an error, it is an exception warning you that the parser found an invalid token.

Moreover: your JSON cannot begin with `<` or `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your support!
The problem was that I had a html header in the php file.

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); is not required.

The following 2 lines at the end of the php-file do the job:

```
$antwort['result'] = "Torte";
echo json_encode($antwort);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will call the data of a **.map** to load them into a matrix using **.push**, but I cannot put the value of the data in the **JSON.parse**

The objective of my exercise is what by selecting a () 1 option to be loaded into the () 2 as an option.

To do this .map the data in the select 1 and then with the event onClick load the data I need to an array to read the options in select 2.

```
const filtraritems = [{ value: 'test', label: 'Probando la lista' }];

const buscarOpciones = items.map(item => (
      <option
        key={item.id}
        onClick={() => {
          const { value } = item;
          filtraritems.push(
            **JSON.parse('{"value": ${items.value}, "label": ${items.label}}')**
          );
          console.log(filtraritems);
        }}
      >
        {item.nombre}
      </option>
    ));
```